# How to start: comet programming with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, comet

I want to start with Comet programming in Java.

What's the first step or requirements?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the first step or requirements?

You would need a server that supports Comet.

Tomcat does and offers an example [Tomcat A/IO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html)
So start from there

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could start with a simple google search, find a suitable article, and then read about it: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/.

If you're particularly adventurous, you can check out the scala lift web framework, which has very good built in support for comet apps: http://liftweb.net/.